In Oracle apex, How to implement a Barcode scanning?
We are developing a functionality that need to read the product code from the Barcode, how to implement that in Oracle APEX 23.2?
I tried to use solution provided here https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=35723:LOGIN:132807331399839:::::
but i didn't succeed, the blog is unavailable
I'm looking for a plugin or something else to achieve this functionality

That app you mention has a link to github. github repo has the plugin. Download the plugin, import it in your application, create a new region and change the region type to "Barcodereader". It seems to works fine for me. I got it to run just like the demo - it opens camera and reads barcode. To add functionality to it, check the help text "The PlugIn can be used in APEX as a region. it uses the html5  capabilties for the camera.
The barcode reader will analyze the image and the value of barcode is read with the event 'apexbcreader'.
You can use a Dynamic Action on this event to process this value further."
There is not barcode reader functionality out of the box in oracle APEX, so you're pretty much on your own. Either implement a javascript library of your choice or use an existing plugin (hard to get support, only the developer will know the details) - but you'll have to do the research yourself.

Eons ago, when we used Oracle Forms (3.0) application, we've also had barcode scanners (like this one; that's just for illustration).
How did that work? Barcode scanner was "emulating" keyboard input. Instead of typing all that data manually, scanner read it from barcode and filled appropriate fields on the screen. There was nothing special we had to do - point and click.
As of Apex, I never did that, but I presume that - if your scanner is just like the one I mentioned above) - it should work the same.

I remember having done something similar over 20 years ago, the user had to position the cursor in a field and then scan. This filled the form item. I'm not sure there is a scanner in the OP's business process. Nowadays all devices have cameras and the ability to read barcodes.
